# Javascript sort fetched data

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am making this menu page, using wordpress as back end. So I fetched the elements, put them to template and appended them to a parent, but now I need to figure out how to sort menu items alphabetically. I don't know if I should write new function after fetching and appending or make sorting a part of the function series that fetches and appends data.

This is what I used:

```
const template = document.querySelector("#menutemplate").content;
const newSection = document.createElement("section");
const parent = document.querySelector("main");

function getMenu() {
    fetch("MY LINK GOES HERE")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(showMenu)
}

function showMenu(menuItems) {
    //console.log(menuItems)
    menuItems.forEach(showItem)
}

function showItem(item) {
    //console.log(item)
    const clone = template.cloneNode(true);
    clone.querySelector(".product").textContent=item.title.rendered
    clone.querySelector(".price").textContent=item.acf.volunteer_price + " dkk";
    newSection.appendChild(clone);
    parent.appendChild(newSection);
}

getMenu();
```

Comment: `menuItems.sort()`?

Comment: You can mark an answer as accepted using the green tick box. Don't edit your title to say the answer was found.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Array.prototype.sort`?

```
function showMenu(menuItems) {
  menuItems
    .sort(a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title))
    .forEach(showItem)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your components should have their data prepared & ready to serve; that means that you should sort the data before it's given to `showMenu`, after you get result from API call.

For instance, given that you have:

```
const menuItems = [
  {label: "Label 1", url: "Url 1"},
  {label: "Label 2", url: "Url 2"},
]
```

you should sort it here...

```
function getMenu(){
  fetch("MY LINK GOES HERE")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(items => items.sort(sortMenuItems)) // <---- Sort goes here
    .then(showMenu)
}
```

with function

```
function sortMenuItems(a, b) {
  const labelA = a.label.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  const labelB = b.label.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase

  if (labelA < labelB ) {
    return -1;
  } else if (labelA > labelB ) {
    return 1;
  } else {
     // labels must be equal
     return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: "Your components should have their data prepared & ready to serve; that means that you should sort the data before it's given to showMenu"

I disagree with this - sorting is a UI concern and should be done within the UI layer :X

Comment: @DanPantry of course, that's why I suggested to sort the data after the api call and before displaying, so we are still in a presentation layer. I'll expand first sentence to clarify :)

Answer (score 0):

After trying out several solutions and not finding how to make javascript sort, I chose different approach to this and fetched already sorted data by adding "&order=asc&orderby=title" to the link I used to fetch data! Saddly I lost a lot of time by not realising this earlier. :))